# Short variabledeclaration with multiple variables

Tags: variables, go, types, declaration

the problem is when you have one variable declared but the other no and you declare them with the := you will get error so what's the solution 
**example**

```golang
var number *int
func(num *int) {
   num,err := function() // that returns int and error
}
```

but here you will get error because num is already declared so what to do 
declare err

**var err error**

but what if i need to use it in another thing which i need short declaration??

Comment: Your question needs further elaboration.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
func f(num *int) {
   num,err := function() // that returns int and error
}
```

if `function` returns (int,error), then you are trying to assign an int to a *int, and that's the reason why you get an error. If `function` returns `*int`, everything works fine.

If you need to redeclare num regardless, you can create a new scope:

```
func f(num *int) {
   {
      num,err:=function()
      // Here, num is int
      ...
   }
}
```